# how to know (in code) that some characters are displayed fine (or not) in the interface of a program made in Delphi

Tags: delphi, interface

Sorry about my english...

I'm trying to make a small program in Delphi 7.
Its interface will have text in my language, which has some characters with diacritics.
If "Language for non-Unicode programs" is set to my language those characters are always displayed fine. That's normal.
If is set to something else, sometimes are displayed fine, sometimes they are not.
How can I know that they can be displayed fine or not...?
Oh, and I can't use Unicode components, only normal.

Only way that I found is to capture the image of one characters into a bitmap and check pixel by pixel. But it's a lot of work to implement, slow and imprecise.

I can use GetSystemDefaultLangID function and know that "Language for non-Unicode programs" is set to something else but still don't know if they are displayed fine or not.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: it's hard to work up enthusiasm for a problem that doesn't exist with unicode

Comment: @David Heffernan I know, and I am sorry about that but I can't find Unicode versions for those components + other issues...

Comment: Yes, but I can't use it (many reasons). Sorry about that too...

Comment: Most people who think they can't use a Unicode delphi would be surprised to find out that they can, and that even the third party components (if you have source code) are easily ported. If you don't have third party source, you should drop those components or replace them even if you stay on D7. :-)

Comment: Why can't you use Unicode components like TNT?

Comment: !Warren P :) This is not the problem. For some components in my program I already use TNTUnicode. I can't drop the ones nonUnicode because I can't find others Unicode that are good for the "job". Also I don't have money to buy a license for Delphi XE. Plus I have tested most of the code from my program into Delphi 200x and it takes too many resources without seeing improvements.

Comment: It can still exist with Unicode, @David. Perhaps it wouldn't be a problem for the *particular* characters that Catalin wishes to use, but in general, we can come up with some character that won't display on some system (because it lacks the right font), and it could be useful to be able to detect that.

Comment: @rob it is my understanding that there is no robust way to detect missing glyphs

Comment: So you don't think Unicode support is an improvement, still? And you're trying to fight your way through glitches that would be GONE if you had a Unicode delphi?

Comment: @David, maybe so, but that makes this question all the more worth asking.

Comment: @rob it's an interesting question but OP's problem would likely dissolve with a modern delphi all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the joys of AnsiStrings encoded using code-pages.   You should not be using AnsiStrings  at all, and you know that, but you say without explaining it that you can't use unicode controls. this seems strange to me. You should be using either:

(a) A Unicode version of Delphi (2009,2010, XE), where String=UnicodeString.

(b) If not that, at least use Proper Unicode controls, such as TNT Controls, and internally use WideString types where you need to store accented or international characters.

Your version of Delphi has String=AnsiString, and you are relying on the locale that your system is set to (as you say in your question) to select the codepage representations of accented characters, a problematic scheme. If you really can't move up from Delphi 7, at least start using WideStrings, and TNT Unicode Controls, but I must say that effort is WASTED you would be better off getting Delphi XE, and just porting to Unicode.

Your question asks "how can I know if they can be stored fine or not?" You can encode and decode using your codepage, and check if anything is replaced with a "?".  The windows function [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example behaves like this.  MBCS is a world of pain, and not worth doing, but you asked how you can find out where the floor falls out from under you, so that API will help you understand your selected encoding rule.

Comment: P I already replied "upstairs" that for some components I already use TNTUnicode. I will try WideCharToMultiByte... Thank you for the idea.

Comment: P, I tested and it shows this: http://img820.imageshack.us/i/capture5t.png/ on English (where the characters with diacritics are displayed fine). If I don't use WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, I get this: http://img269.imageshack.us/i/capture4dx.png/ (I think this is what Pol described on his computer). I'm not sure that it can be used because even if the characters are displayed properly, the function is returning '?' for most of them. But if I didn't understood what you said I should do please tell me...

Answer (score 1):

Use WideCharToMultiByte Function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx and check lpUsedDefaultChar parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    ACP: Integer;
begin
    ACP := GetACP;
    Caption := 'CP' + IntToStr(ACP);
    if ACP = 1250 then
        Caption := Caption + ' is okay for Romanian language';
end;
```

Comment: @Pol Thank you. But the problem is that is not working better than "Result := GetSystemDefaultLangID = my_lang_id". It's returning False when GetSystemDefaultLangID <> my_lang_id but I can see that the characters are displayed fine.

Comment: @Pol Oh, and when GetSystemDefaultLangID <> my_lang_id and the characters are not displayed fine, it's returning True...

Comment: @Catalin What language are you testing? Can you send also test characters?

Comment: @Pol It's Romanian language. I don't know if they will display ok to others but here they are: ăîâşţĂÎÂŞŢ

Comment: @Catalin For what "Language for non-Unicode programs" this happens: "when GetSystemDefaultLangID <> my_lang_id and the characters are not displayed fine, it's returning True"

Comment: @Pol That's the thing: a guy taught me how to "simulate" another ansicodepage without changing the language. I do this because I don't know exactly why on other computers (also set to "English") are not displayed properly so I can't reproduce the problem directly. What do I do: I virtualize the application with ThinApp and I set as compiling parameter "AnsiCodePage=1252" (US (ANSI), for Romanian is 1250). If I do wrong then I'm sorry...

Comment: @Catalin When I set "Language for non-Unicode programs" to English, CheckRegionalCharacters of course returns False and some of test characters are displayed without accents. I am not using ThinApp. Tested with characters you wrote above (ăîâşţĂÎÂŞŢ). But when I set "Language for non-Unicode programs" to Polish which is CP-1250, both my function return True and characters are displayed properly.

Comment: @Pol On my computer (and others as well) it displays this http://img818.imageshack.us/i/capturegoodromanian.png/ on Romanian, this http://img708.imageshack.us/i/capturegoodenglish.png/ on English. But some users reported this on English: http://img232.imageshack.us/i/capturenotgood.png/ I saw the "behavior" from your computer also some time ago but since it just loses some accents it's not such a big problem. Maybe it depends on Windows version/SP/updates, installed fonts, how was installed first time etc.

Comment: By the way, I have Windows XP SP3, latest updates, MS European Union Expansion font Update, first time installed with Romanian. But I have installed a few times XP SP3 in VirtualBox directly on English and there was no change. Oh, and in my program all components have EASTEUROPE_CHARSET.

Comment: @Pol Maybe the function with CodePage will work but I have no way to test it properly... With ThinApp the code from the program is returning 1250 even if the "environment" is set to 1252. But thank you.

Comment: @John I am not sure... do you have to use ThinApp in your production app?

Comment: @Pol For now I'm using ThinApp just for tests.

Comment: @John It seems that this tool is not good for testing this thing. I mean you have strange results. Not sure but seems like this tool virtualises only some resources. Both `WideCharToMultiByte` and `GetACP` should be sufficient for checking this if we assume you are using standard windows fonts and Romanian accent characters.

Comment: @Pol Yes, it's possible (about ThinApp been not good for testing) but I can't be 100% sure... I will ask about that on their forum.

Answer (score 0):

Since this has been on my research list for a while, but didn't reach the top of that list yet, I can only help you out with a few links.

You will need to to quite a bit of experimentation :-)

When using Unicode, you can use functions [ScriptGetCMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetGlyphIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to test if a code point is in the font.
When not using Unicode, you can use the function [GetGlyphIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are few Delphi translations of these functions around. [This Borland Newsgroup thread](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200511/0511273665.html) has a few hints on using [GetGlyphIndices in Delphi](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22GetGlyphIndices%22%20delphi).
Here is a search [ScriptGetCMap in Delphi](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ScriptGetCMap%22%20delphi).

[This page](http://tingmarprog.wordpress.com/2008/08/04/moned-abistavad-winapid-kui-unicode-vcl-kirjutate/) has a list of some interesting API calls that might help you further.

An extra handicap is that because not all fonts contain all characters, so Windows can do font substitution for you.
I'm not sure how to figure out that, but it is something you have to check for too.

Good luck :-)

Comment: @John: You are welcome; please let us know the results as it will help others with similar problems.